# Generate grouped time series based on Open and Close date

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data-transform

I have a dataset with 3 columns namely their ID and open and close week. Some IDs do not have close week yet, so they have close week equals to NA. But all IDs have open week.

```
set.seed(1990)
mydf <- tibble(id = as.vector(outer(letters, letters, paste0))[1:10]
               , open_week = rep(1:5,2)) %>%
  mutate(close_week = open_week + sample(1:5,10, replace = T)) %>%
  arrange(open_week)
mydf
# some are closed, some are not closed # if not closed, set to NA
mydf$close_week[sample(c(TRUE, FALSE),10, replace = T, prob = c(0.1,0.9))] <- NA

> mydf
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   id    open_week close_week
   <chr>     <int>      <int>
 1 aa            1          2
 2 fa            1          4
 3 ba            2          4
 4 ga            2         NA
 5 ca            3          7
 6 ha            3          6
 7 da            4          6
 8 ia            4          5
 9 ea            5          7
10 ja            5          9
```

From the data above, I'm generating its weekly metrics as below

```
have <- seq_len(max(mydf$close_week, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  set_names("Week") %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(opened = sum(Week == mydf$open_week),
         closed = sum(Week == mydf$close_week, na.rm = T),
         active_ages_med = list(Week - mydf$open_week[Week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                     Week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                   max(mydf$close_week, na.rm = T) +1,
                                                                   mydf$close_week)]),
         closed_ages_med = list((Week - mydf$open_week[Week == mydf$close_week]) %>% na.omit()),
         active = length(act_ages_med),
         active_ages_med = median(active_ages_med),
         closed_ages_med = median(closed_ages_med)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(active_growth = (active - lag(active))*100/lag(active))
have
> have
# A tibble: 9 x 7
   Week opened closed active_ages_med closed_ages_med active active_growth
  <int>  <int>  <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>  <int>       <dbl>
1     1      2      0          0           NA        2        NA  
2     2      2      1          0            1        3        50  
3     3      2      0          1           NA        5        66.7
4     4      2      2          1            2.5      5         0  
5     5      2      1          1.5          1        6        20  
6     6      0      2          2            2.5      4       -33.3
7     7      0      2          3.5          3        2       -50  
8     8      0      0          4.5         NA        2         0  
9     9      0      1          7            4        1       -50
```

With `have` I'm tracking the weekly active IDs, based on the Open and Close weeks.
What's lacking with `have` is the contribution of the active IDs based on some predefined groupings.
For example, let's say I decide to classify active IDs based on their active age, namely IDs with `Active Age < 1 day` and IDs with `Active Age >= 1 day`.

Therefore, instead of having the number of active IDs for each week, I should be able to get the number of active IDs for each week by the different groups, and then calculate the growth rate of each group.
Note that each ID may have changed their grouping classification depending on the week of reference and its open week. For example in week 1, ID `fa` with `open_week` equals to 1 will be classified as `Active Age < 1 day` but in week 3 ID `fa` should be counted as part of `Active Age >= 1 day` group.

```
want <- tibble(Week = rep(c(1:9),each=2),
               group = rep(c('Active Age < 1 day','Active Age >= 1 day'),9),
               active = c(2,0,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,0,4,0,2,0,2,0,1),
               active_growth = c(NA,NA,0,NA,0,200,0,0,0,33,-100,0,0,-50,0,0,0,-50))
> want
# A tibble: 18 x 4
    Week group               active active_growth
   <int> <chr>                <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1 Active Age < 1 day       2          NA
 2     1 Active Age >= 1 day      0          NA
 3     2 Active Age < 1 day       2           0
 4     2 Active Age >= 1 day      1          NA
 5     3 Active Age < 1 day       2           0
 6     3 Active Age >= 1 day      3         200
 7     4 Active Age < 1 day       2           0
 8     4 Active Age >= 1 day      3           0
 9     5 Active Age < 1 day       2           0
10     5 Active Age >= 1 day      4          33
11     6 Active Age < 1 day       0        -100
12     6 Active Age >= 1 day      4           0
13     7 Active Age < 1 day       0           0
14     7 Active Age >= 1 day      2         -50
15     8 Active Age < 1 day       0           0
16     8 Active Age >= 1 day      2           0
17     9 Active Age < 1 day       0           0
18     9 Active Age >= 1 day      1         -50
```

Here's a visual aid that captures the ID age as week passes by

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I used the `rowwise()` to get the desired results

```
  # calculate up to the last week
  week_last <- max(mydf$close_week, na.rm = T)


  # create complete week grid
  df <- as_tibble(data.frame(week = seq(from = min(mydf$open_week, na.rm = T)
                                       , to = max(mydf$close_week, na.rm = T), by = 1)))
  
  want <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(act_ticket_number_list = list(mydf$id[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                            week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                          week_last +1,
                                                                          mydf$close_week)]),
           act_ticket_age_list = list(week - mydf$open_week[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                              week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                                     week +1,
                                                                            mydf$close_week)]),
           
           act_number_group_0_1 = list(act_ticket_number_list[act_ticket_age_list < 1]),
           act_number_group_1_above = list(act_ticket_number_list[act_ticket_age_list >= 1]),

           act_ages_group_0_1 = sum(act_ticket_age_list < 1, na.rm = T),
           act_ages_group_1_above = sum(act_ticket_age_list >= 1, na.rm = T),

           active_cnt = length(act_ticket_age_list)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    dplyr::select(!where(is.list))
  
  want

# A tibble: 9 x 4
   week act_ages_group_0_1 act_ages_group_1_above active_cnt
  <dbl>              <int>                  <int>      <int>
1     1                  2                      0          2
2     2                  2                      1          3
3     3                  2                      3          5
4     4                  2                      3          5
5     5                  2                      4          6
6     6                  0                      4          4
7     7                  0                      2          2
8     8                  0                      2          2
9     9                  0                      1          1
```